# ReactJS: Convert EpochTime since 1970 to just now, 1 hour ago, 2 hours ago, 1 day ago, 3 days ago

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have this time in

```
1621401215944
```

this is epoch time since 1970.

In JS, how to you convert it into just now, 1 hour ago, 2 hours ago, 1 day ago, 3 days ago?

Can momentjs perform the conversion?

Comment: The correct name for what you call "epoch time" is a [time value](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [yes it can](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

(That's an epoch time in milliseconds, by the way, which is common in JavaScript land. UNIX epoch times in general are expressed in seconds.)

```js
function convert() {
  document.getElementById("y").value = moment(+document.getElementById("x").value).fromNow();
}

document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("input", convert);
convert();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<input type="number" value="1621401215944" step="3600000" id="x">
<input readonly id="y">
```